# Android native app testing using Selenium

Tags: selenium, appium, nativeapplication

Can anyone one please guide me ... how to work with native apps with Selenium. I have Appium and native driver for this, but it won't work for me. While running, I am getting the error in the console.

"*Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure*."

What's wrong?

Comment: hi Ronak,i have tried it, but i didn't get sol. if u aware of it plz let me know.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/appium-discuss

There are lots of beginner questions on there and they might help with a question like that.  This is too broad for stackoverflow