# Does Selendroid run on android?

Tags: android, web-testing, selendroid

What I want to do is with my android phone open a web page and programmatically press buttons and insert data.

Just like automated Mobile web testing

My problem is that I tried to add Selendroid - client / selendroid driver jars but it doesn't compile...

is this even the purpose of those Selendroid? I cant seem to understand this issue.

can anyone recommend a god explanation link or a different method to accomplish my purpose.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this below links
 [link1](http://www.methodsandtools.com/tools/selendroid.php)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227399/android-native-app-testing-using-selenium)